# Perforce: List all files which are not having latest version?

Tags: perforce

How to list files which are not having latest version in Perforce?

Is there a command in Perforce which will allow to find out this information?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
p4 sync -n
```

lists what it *would* do if it got the latest revisions. This is a list of files that you do not currently have, or files that are not at the latest version. (You can also do this via P4V -- Get Revision...->Preview).